# Eclipse: Связать jar файл с исходными файлами проекта, в котором он создавался

Tags: java, eclipse

Есть два объёмных проекта, один из которых (A) использует второй (Б) в виде jar файла. Есть ли возможность "сопоставить" .class файлам в этом jar-архиве их .java-файлы в открытом параллельно проекте Б?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

пересобрать А, добавив в него исходники или собрать исходники отдельным jar и добавить к А артефакту